# Internet reachability not working properly in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, reachability

I am working on an application which continously tracking internet connectivity and upload some data, app have the feature that when internet is not available it saves data(photos) offline and on internet availability it uploads the data. My app working fine but sometimes its not chechking internet and when i turned off my device wifi and again turn on, It is working, So can anybody please tell me whats wrong here that stuck me? my reachability code is as below:

**code**

```
- (void)reachabilityCheck
{
    /* Internet checking  */
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    reach.reachableOnWWAN = YES;
    [reach startNotifier];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (internetStatus != NotReachable) {
        //Develop By Payal
        if(self.internetConnection == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Connection active");
            self.internetConnection = 1;
        }
        //Develop By Payal Done
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Connection inactive");
        self.internetConnection = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

Put bellow code in your `viewDidLoad` method
it call the instantly using notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:)
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];



//Net Connection Chack
- (void)checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes

    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No Internet Connection\nPlease Check The Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alrt show];

            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI");
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

i hope this usefull you

Comment: Hello nikunj thanks you so much for quick answer,I just have noticed that when i am turn off and again turn on my iPhone's wifi,then uploading data working,so can you tell me what is the issue?and where i have to put your code dear?please help me i stuck to this point since 1 week.and i have hope that you can help me...:(

Comment: your code is deprecated, this code are not working sum time. if my code is working so up vote and accept my answer  @jigarjims7

Comment: ok brother let me try this first.hope you will help if problem persists.:)

Comment: hello,Same issue still remains..please help me,problem is when am first time making my wifi on,uploading not working,but when i just turn off and again on the wifi uploading starts..and working fine.

Comment: i used reachability in appdelegate and have taken a timer for checking internet by specific time.I again want to explain my case is,When i am uploading y media in offline mode,it saved in device,then i am killing app from background and turn wifi on,then reopen the app so now internet is coming but in this case its not working..

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you might not observe any connection change.

I'm not sure what trigger did you use so that your code is working when you turn off and on your wifi connection.

Instead of manually check the connection using timer, you could use `Reachability` class provided by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

You could import the class and then register for any connection change in your viewDidLoad (or appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method if you want global observer).

```
//AppDelegate.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) Reachability *reachability;

//AppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityDidChange:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
    [self.reachability startNotifier];
}

#pragma mark - Reachability notification
- (void)reachabilityDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    Reachability *reachability = (Reachability *)[notification object];

    if ([reachability isReachable]) {
        NSLog(@"There is connection");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unreachable");
    }
}
```

Edit:
you define these 2 following scenario to test your code.

1. it is working in case when i am killing the app ,reopen the app and after that i turn on the wifi
2. when i first turn on the wifi and then reopen the app,it is not working

In scenario 1, your observer know the connection change since the app is still alive. However, in scenario 2 your app does not have any info on connection change since there are no change after you open your app.

If you want to achieve what you want (upload media to server) in scenario 2, then Reachability change is not the tool that you need.

Comment: i used reachability in appdelegate and have taken a timer for checking internet by specific time.I again want to explain my case is,When i am uploading y media in offline mode,it saved in device,then i am killing app from background and turn wifi on,then reopen the app so now internet is coming but in this case its not working

Comment: Your scenario is like this. 1. App offline -> saving to device  2. you kill app 3. you turn connection 4. you reopen the app. Since the notification for connection is not being run at all during those four phase, your code surely will not working. Try to skip step number 2 and turn on the connection without killing your app.

Comment: So what should be done if i dont want to skip step2?as i already know by skippping step2 my code is working very nicely,and that's why i posted this question for specific case.it is working in watsapp..!

Comment: It is working in case when i am killing the app ,reopen the app and after that i turn on the wifi,but when i first turn on the wifi and then reopen the app,it is not working...!!! any idea?

Comment: That deserve another question. One strategy that i had in mind is implement custom flag to your media in your local database. So something like `isMediaSentToServer` and proceed to send the media to server during `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function.

Comment: I am not getting your way of solution,How to manage that flag,pls help